# Which encryption algorithm do external hard drives use?

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, encryption

if external data carriers are encrypted via the Finder, which encryption do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are encrypted with the AES encryption algorithm.

After you have encrypted the external disk, you can open Terminal and run this command to check the encryption:

```
diskutil cs list
```

It will show the disk, and then something like this in the output:

> ```
>     Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
> ```

Here AES-XTS means that the main encryption algorithm is AES, and that the XTS block cipher mode is used.

The XTS block cipher mode is used primarily to prevent that identical blocks of data (for example "never used space") encrypts into the same encrypted value. This is done by actually having 2 AES keys and a process where the data is continuously "tweaked" specifically to avoid such a problem.

If you have chosen to format the drive as APFS and not HFS+, then it won't show up when running the above mentioned command. You can check if that is the case by running:

```
diskutil apfs list
```

This will show the disk as being APFS formatted. However, it won't show you which encryption type is being used on the drive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I enter the command "diskutil cs list"  I get this as output: No CoreStorage logical volume groups found

Comment: Did you format the drive with APFS? Then that’s why. The encryption algorithm is the same though.

Comment: As well ... as. Two USB sticks are connected to my Mac, one is formatted with "APFS" and one with "Mac OS Extended (journaled)". Neither of the two are recognized by the mere command "diskutil cs list". I think this command is there to recognize "Fusion Drive".

Comment: @DarwinOSX `diskutil cs list` will list CoreStorage volumes, which are used for HFS+ volumes that're encrypted and/or set up as Fusion Drives. For APFS volumes, use `diskutil apfs list` instead.

Comment: Gordon Davisson, they solved my problem. If you like, you can write it in reply so I can mark it as "solved". Thank you

Comment: Actually that won't work - it will display the drive yes, but it won't show the encryption status. That's why I didn't include that command in my answer (I considered it).